Mutable state not able to change value when passed as argument
I am building a screen in compose to transition my app from views to jetpack.
I cannot figure-out how to pass a parameters to a composable and still allow it to be modified. I try to break down the screen into small components.
here is the code:
@Composable
fun MyScreen(...) 
{

    var showBottomSheet by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }


    Scaffold(
    ...

       MyBottomSheet(showBottomSheet)
    ...
    ) 
}

@Composable
fun MyBottomSheet(showBottomSheet: Boolean) {
...
   ModalBottomSheet(
        onDismissRequest = {
            showBottomSheet = false
        },
        sheetState = sheetState
    ) {
        Button(onClick = {
        }) {
            Text("Hide bottom sheet")
            showBottomSheet = false
        }
    }}

Any idea who to pass the mutable showBottomSheet into another component ?

@Composable
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
fun MyScreen(...) 
{

    var showBottomSheet by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState()


    Scaffold(
    ...

       MyBottomSheet(showBottomSheet, sheetState, {showBottomSheet = it})
    ...
    ) 
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun MyBottomSheet(showBottomSheet: Boolean, sheetState: SheetState, onStateChange: (Boolean) -> Unit) {
    if(showBottomSheet) {
        val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
        ModalBottomSheet(
            onDismissRequest = {
                onStateChange(false)
            },
            sheetState = sheetState
        ){
            Button(onClick = {
                scope.launch {
                    sheetState.hide()
                }.invokeOnCompletion { if (!sheetState.isVisible) { onStateChange(false) } }
            }) {
                Text("Hide bottom sheet")
            }
        }
    }
}

pass a lambda to update the variable instead, this way, you still update the variable declated in MyScreen inside of other child composables

Read more about how this is supposed to be done in Compose here: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/architecture

Thanks for the answer, I tried but the sheetState do not accept showBottomSheet

my bad, I edited my answer based on this post: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/components/bottom-sheets

also, you will receive a red underline if you do not use a padding from the scaffold, just saying
